# Multiple Python leads to installation of boto at wrong location

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto

I am on Centos7. I have multiple Python versions (Totally newbie in python). 
One at my root inside folder name Python-2.6.6 which i installed following these steps :

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/Python-2.6.6.tgz
 tar -zxvf Python-2.6.6.tgz
 cd Python-2.6.6
 sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
 make 
 make install
```

However there is also a Python folder at `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
Which i have no idea how got created . 
Now i installed boto using

```
sudo yum -y install python-pip
sudo pip install boto
```

installation ended with comments
*Installing collected packages: boto*
*Successfully installed boto-2.47.0*

Now when i do `python --version` , I do get `Python 2.6.6` which is expected

```
which python : /usr/local/bin/python
```

but when i do `import boto`
i get 
**import boto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named boto**

WHY YOU NO IMPORT?Please help

Comment: I think your Centos already had Python, which you now conflicted with your other installation. Additionally, python-pip RPM package installs packages into the *system* python. In addition, [Python 2.6 was *EOL*ed a long time ago already](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-September/128287.html), full of holes and so on, and Python 2.7 follows it - if you're compiling your own Python, why not go for the fresh **3**.6?!

Comment: Are you suggesting to uninstall Python 2.6 ? Can't I somehow use any of the existing python installation?

Comment: You **did** install your Python 2.6.6 from source there. Furthermore, it wasn't the source even for 2.6.9 which was the latest released Python 2.6 version, but broken [2.6.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/) without any Centos-specific patches.

Comment: After the `make install` you possibly overwrote your system Python... it depends on the settings you used to actually install it. The Python-2.6.6 directory was used to build it, but `make install` threw the files into `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib/` etc... The best course of action would be to remove these files, as they will probably clash with your system's Python.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance , but which files should i remove . Is it advisable to remove python . Here people are suggesting against it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724471/how-to-uninstall-python2-6

Comment: I don't have Centos 7. I cannot see the system, but you've already messed up the system by installing another python into the system path, so I'd say you'd want to remove *the* python version that you just installed with `make install`. Perhaps Nab there would know Centos better.

Comment: Notice that the *other* question details about removing the *preinstalled* Python 2.6. In your case, Centos comes preinstalled with Python *2.7*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Hi, need little help. i did rm /usr/local/bin/python* , after that , which python gives /usr/bin/python(which is the preinstalled python dir). but when i type python, i am getting /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory  . Any idea why this is happening? how can i fix it ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Created a symlink between ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python , it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOs 7 is delivered with python 2.7 by default.

You installed boto with pip wich is "bind" to python 2.7, that's why you can't import boto using python 2.6. pip is bind to python2.7, cause it's the default version in CentOs 7.

You should use virtualenv. It allows you to create a python environnement with a specific python version and install the modules needed.

Example:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/my_project
cd ./my_project
source bin/active
```

Now you're in a python virtualenv. The first command points to python2.7, but you can make it point to any python version installed (compiled, from repos etc.). Once you sourced the `active` file you can install modules using `pip`

**Edit**

To run a script using your virtualenv (without sourcing `./bin/active`):

```
/home/user/my_project/bin/python /path/my_script.py
```

If you use this command :

```
source bin/activate
```

Then you can use `pip` to add a lib to the virtualenv.

**Edit 2**

So, you're on Centos 7, wich is provided with python 2.7. You want to use python 2.6 with a specific script.

1. Install python 2.6 (let's say in `/usr/bin/python2.6`)
2. Create a virtuanlenv with python 2.6 :

   virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 my_venv
3. Enter the virtualenv

   cd my_env
   source bin/activate
4. Check the python version (should return python 2.6.x)

   python
5. Install a module with pip :

   pip install boto

`boto` will be installed with python 2.6, so you will be able to use your script.

If for some reason `pip` is not installed :

```
yum install python-pip
```

Comment: I think i cant do that because i am running python script from a Jenkins Job which will run in the same shell .

Comment: If this is true, and the Python 2.7 is installed in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib/python2.7` then I guess removing `/usr/local/bin/python*` would be safe?

Comment: @user2991413 you can always do it, just point the script to `/foo/bar/baz/my_project/venv/bin/python` and it should work.

Comment: @user2991413 Antti Haapla is right. Let me edit my answer to point that out.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I can't change the script. and yes i do see python, python 2 and python 2.7 inside /usr/bin and subdir /sitepackege under  /usr/lib/python2.7 . Should i do rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python/  ?

Comment: @user2991413, no dont `rm` the folder. Many tools delivered with centos use python

Comment: @NabIlovich it is about the python they installed by *accident* with `make install`.

Comment: Can i somehow install boto in Python 2.6 . I understand that pip will always point to Python 2.7 but is there any other way to install boto modules in a specific directory . May be by easy_install ? or will creating a symlink work ?

Comment: the question is: why do you again want an obsolete version of Python, one soon not supported by boto anymore

Comment: And that even instead of some proper Centos-packaged Python 2.6.

Comment: The machine i am trying to create a back up for uses Python 2.6 . I wanted to be safe so i was trying to have versions of all the dependencies match.