# Can't install MySQL-python [CentOS]

Tags: python, mysql, linux, python-2.7, centos

I need mysql-python on my CentOS 7 server to run a script I wrote. I haven't found any success installing it I always get the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-
build-mpl_yksf/mysql-python/
```

I am running CentOS 7 and accessing my machine through ssh.

I have tried the following:
-[Installing mysql-python on Centos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4380931/9117755)
-[can't install MySQL-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073541/cant-install-mysql-python)
python-dev is installed hopefully for the right version of python, gcc is also installed in fact I run:

```
# yum groupinstall "Developper Tools"
```

-[mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface/37358547#37358547)
Tried the solution provided here to install the package directly in the same directory as python 3.7 instead of the default one which was the one containing python 2.7:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323532/yum-install-package-name-to-different-directory
I
    # yum --installroot=/usr/local/bin/ --releasever=/ install MySQL-python
Per this I can't simply uninstall python 2.6:
-[How to uninstall Python2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724471/how-to-uninstall-python2-6)

And I don't think simply creating an alias will solve my problem generally python 3 launches automatically not python 2 but my problem is regarding mysql-python

Essentially I think I have narrowed it down to the fact that I don't have mysql-python accessible to pthon 3.7 for some reason. It seems my 2 versions of python are somehow conflicting. I am wondering what I can do to fix this ? Before you suggest I tried running my program through python 2 but some exceptions I have to catch were not yet available.

All I want to do is get rid of this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Could someone please help me ? I wasn't sure whether it was better to post in unix.stackexchange.com but it seems appropriate to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting (`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mpl_yksf/mysql-python/`) is because of a missing package `ConfigParser`.

In Python 3, `ConfigParser` was renamed to be `configparser` (all lowercase) to comply with PEP 8 standards. As of now, MySQL-python has not been updated to support Python 3.

You are left with two choices:

1. Use Python 2 for whatever you are trying to do. This implies using pip2 command instead of pip3.
2. Use an alternative package, such as mysqlclient.

To install mysqlclient, you will first need [libmysqlclient-devel](https://pkgs.org/download/libmysqlclient16-devel). Then you can install the Python 3 module via pip.

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```